# Enabling Apple Wallet / Apple Pay on Non-US iPhone

Tags: wallet, apple-pay

I have an iPhone that I own outright from Australia (Model A1586). I have recently relocated to the US and have a US Visa card that is compatible with Apple Pay.

However, I do not have any Wallet or Pay options on my iPhone at all.

Is there any way I can add this to my phone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> General -> Language & Region -> Region` and choose United States. After that Apple Pay should appear in the main Settings menu.